# Why can't I set a cookie in PHP which can be used in an If statement on the next page?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to create a cookie within PHP.
By using the following code :

```
<?php
//Writing Cookie Data
setcookie("Enabled", "True", time()+3600);
setcookie("Username", $username);
//Test if cookie is set. / Just for test purposes.
echo $_COOKIE["Username"];
?>
```

After the cookie is set I've used a code to let users go to the next page by pressing an image (link).
This one :

```
<a href="folder/index.php"><img src="image.png"></img></a>
```

And I've used a code on the next page which will check if the cookie exists.
This one :

```
<!-- Security Start -->
<?php
If (isset($_COOKIE["Enabled"])) {

}
else
{
header("Location: ../");
}
?>
<!-- Security Stop -->
```

And when the user goes to the next page he'll just be redirected to the folder specified if the security cookie doesn't exist.
I've probably setup everything correctly, and I've already checked many things, but I can't come up with a solution to this problem. The cookie should exist, and exsists.
Because the echo code works on the same page.
But after going to the next page; the cookie is suddenly gone, it doesn't exist.
Echo and using it in an If statement on the next page are both not possible.

Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: You should use SESSION rather than COOKIE for security stuff.  Cookies are sent out in plain text to the users and can be manipulated and/or intercepted.  The SESSION is stored in memory on the server.

Comment: You can view cookies in firebug / web dev...maybe its has to do with your browsers cookie settings?

Comment: I've already tried using sessions. But the script I'm securing is already using Sessions; so I'm getting an error that the session already started. So I thought I'd do it this way. I know it's less secure but else it'll be conflicting with the other script.

Comment: I fixed it! Thanks to @PatrickEvans I finally got the script to work with sessions, the cache also worked by the way, but now I'm going to use sessions! Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You do not see the cookie because you have not set the PATH argument for [`setcookie`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)
Using a path of "/" will enable the use of the cookie anywhere on the domain, otherwise the cookie can only be seen by scripts in the folder and sub folders of the executing script.

```
setcookie("Enabled", "True", time()+3600, "/");
setcookie("Username", $username,time()+3600,"/");
```

But as with the comments do not use cookies in place of sessions, as cookies can be easily faked.

If you already have session started you do not need to do session_start() again, if you have php 5.4 or higher you can check session status with [session_status](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php)

```
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start();}
```

or if it is lower than 5.4

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
```

As per the [user submitted comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php#Hcom111945) on the session_status page

Comment: @user2718919 updated answer to include a way for you to check for session handling, that way you can keep this in the proper place,$_SESSION, and avoid security holes

Comment: Thanks. But I've already tried using sessions. With the scripts I desribed in my question I was trying to secure an index page. But that page is already using PHP sessions. So it will give errors if I want another session to be started. The problem is that I couldn't create seperate sessions. So I started to use cookies, what indeed was stupid of me. But I couldn't find a way to start another seperate session and distinguish them from each other within the code. So whenever the script I was trying to secure tried to start a session, it would give errors. And I couldn't find a solution to that.

Comment: @user2718919, using the above if statements will prevent the scripts from trying to start another session, you dont need another session, if your index page already starts the session then you are already able to use $_SESSION

Comment: @user2718919 dont forget to mark the question as answered if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Cookies**

Some things I would do to debug this if you want cookies:

I would check the path as stated by Patrick

I would look at the return value of setcookie and see if it tells you it failed.

In your browser you should be able to see a list of all cookies, and you can check and see if the cookie was actually set.  Again, look at the path here.

**Using a session instead**

However, I agree with the session recommendation by developerwjk, one way to do it is to make sure you call 'ob_start()' as one of the first things that happens on the page, it will then buffer the output and give you time to manipulate $_SESSION.  Make sure you then call ob_flush(), to flush the buffer once you are finished with all session stuff.. I believe otherwise it will automatically flush the buffer at the end of the page but it might just discard everything..

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it working with sessions! So for security I will use sessions now.